# Web Application - Scheduling large amounts time-sensitive tasks, dynamically

Tags: web-applications, queue, scheduled-tasks, worker

I'm working on a web application where I'll need to schedule time-sensitive tasks for each User. However, I'm not sure what sort of process would handle this.  Queue workers come to mind, but I'm not sure if they handle actions that need to occur at an exact time. The rules are roughly as follows:

1) I need to be able to schedule a task for a User, that when executed, is run at a specific time (down to the second) i.e. Schedule task at 8:30:33 for execution at 8:35:19

2) Tasks need to be scheduled per User, and very frequently (potentially every few minutes)

3) I need to be able to update a scheduled task.  i.e. At 8:30:33 we schedule a task for execution at 8:35:19, however, at 8:32 an event occurs and we now need to update that execution time to 8:37:22

The task that would need to be executed would be an endpoint in my application which will update a DB record.

Cron jobs don't really seem appropriate. Or perhaps MySQL Events?  Is there another sort of process that would facilitate this type of behavior?

Comment: I'm curious why you think that cron jobs don't seem appropriate?  This is what poped into my head when I read the title to your question:  https://open.buffer.com/cronjob-generates-4-million-year/

Comment: Why aren't cron jobs appropriate? Also, if the changes are only time sensitive to the point where it needs to be done when someone looks, you could run whatever code you would cron (if required) when people view the page needed

Comment: @Jonathan hm thats interesting. though the Cron job in that case is adding the entries to a Queue, which is what I was curious about.  It seems they were able to fire Queued jobs at specific times

Comment: @Alfie i had dismissed crons because the tasks need to be checked down to the second.  It's my understanding that cron jobs can only be run every minute at most.  Also this is part of an iOS api so running the code when people look isn't really an option.  The process needs to be running on its own in this case

Comment: @djt I think you can specify to the second, but if you couldn't, perhaps you could set the allowed script execution time to ~60 seconds and loop within the script to check for second precision?